# Performance of an IF statement on back-end versus view (razor)

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

My project is built on the MS's MVC4 platform in C#.

I'm feeding a View Model that represents a row from a table in the front-end, and i have to add a IF clause that may turn this row invalid, which representation in the table would be a row filled with '-' in all of it's collumns.

In order to fill the View Model i have to iterate through a certain number of objects, and i have to do that once again in the front-end to place them correctly.

I want to know, in terms of performance, which would be faster:

1 - Fill the View Model with lots of '-', one for each object iterated and then iterate once again to fill all collumns with the same information.

2 - Place a boolean flag on the ViewModel, indicating that this row is invalid and consequently skiping the iteration on the back-end. When i reach front-end i would ask for the flag, and in case it's true i would iterate trough the collumns filling them.

I know it may seem a little bit obvious that the second option is smarter, but i know that code runs way faster in the back-end that in a view, so in this case i'm confused.

P.S. I know the best way would be to try it, but i have some tasks to do before i can test, and just in the case anyone has experienced a similar situation i'd be glad to hear the results.

P.S.2 - I hardly doubt this is the case of a question which answer is 'strictly based on opinion'

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the first test, with some code inside the view (.cshtml) it took 17 minutes to be rendered, not just that if clause, but with some other calcs.

Considering it's not a big amount of data, the performance was a huge disappointment.  So I decided to rewrite the whole function in the back-end so the view would do what it was conceived to, just show information 100% pre-calculated.

With all the processing in the back-end, the same action took about 1 minute to be rendered.

Lesson learned, do not, or at least, avoid to the max coding on a view because it's performance is awful.

Comment: Your question isn't really clear, that could be a reason for a downvote.

Comment: Also speaking to the performance of Razor, views are compiled by razor so the performance difference should be close to nil. Not sure the test case you were running to get a 17 minute render, but one likely cause is you might have been lazy loading data from the database.

Comment: @doogle I'm using entity framework, and i'm aware of how it works with his navigation properties. I did include them before the calcs, but the old view had quite too much processing in it, including long iterations that justify 17 minutes. I'm not saying that razor is 17 times slower, but it's slower enough to disencourage me from ever trying to calculate something with him again haha. 

I know i wasn't clear enough, i'm sorry, i guess my main doubt at the time would be straight like 'How much slower would be processing data in Razor in comparison to the back-end'